# infoPlist Property is not working with EXPO project for iTunes connect

Tags: location, expo, app-store-connect, manifest, info-plist

I had submitted my app twice to apple store and it's being rejected due to privacy getting the user information like location

I built my project with EXPO and after adding infoPlist property as a child to ios object as mentioned in EXPO documentations

https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/#system-permissions-dialogs-on-ios

and rebuilt a new binary as mentioned in this issue page

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1570

still the app having the same behavior and the permission request is not being changes

Kindly help with that

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "slug": "xxx",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "3.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "xxx",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist" : {
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" : 
        "APP uses your location to get you accurate data about Prayer Times and Qibla Direction",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" : 
        "App uses your location to get you accurate data about Prayer Times and Qibla Direction",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": 
        "App uses your location to get you accurate data about Prayer Times and Qibla Direction",
        "NSLocationUsageDescription" : 
        "App uses your location to get you accurate data about Prayer Times and Qibla Direction",
        "buildNumber" : "2.0.2",
        "CFBundleVersion" : "2.0.2",
        "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "2.0.1"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode" : 5,
      "package": "xxx"
    }
    }

  }
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and i could not find any active / recent post about it.